# Facebook client side authorization flow and get access_token for all scenarios like when scope for an app changes, etc

Tags: javascript, facebook, authorization

I am trying to do 3 simple things using JS thru a client side authorization flow :

1. Check if the user is logged in. If not, display the login dialog with proper scope.
2. If user is already logged into Facebook on the browser, then ensure the app has been authorized (if not, display the Authorize dialog).
3. If user has already authorized the app then ensure that the access_token on the authResponse has the right scope (permissions) required by the app. (if not, redisplay the authorize dialog for the new permissions).

I am trying to leverage js sdk for this, without wanting to write any hand-coded dialog's etc, since the sdk handles the browsers/devices nuances automagically.

I could not find this properly described anywhere either on FB documentation or otherwise. (no documentation around the fact that the permissions/scope for the app can change post authorization).

Thanks you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After an arduous attempt I have this working and here are the steps to do this with the minimum amount of code.

**The Approach **

1. Use fb-login-button to facilitate login. Login Button is the only thing that is displayed when the user first arrives on the page. All other forms are 'hidden', forcing the user to click on this button before being able to go forward.
2. setup onlogin="function();" on the fb-login-button - so that you can hide the login-button and display the rest of the forms/etc for the user to proceed on your app. Please note that onlogin is called only once (either when the user logs in or authorizes the app with the new scope) - so it is safe to always hide the login-button and display the remaining of the page/form for the user to proceed.
3. ***The most important step*** : use the same fb-login-button to also do the authorization with the right scope : so even if the user is logged in - force the user to click the login-button. fb-login-button in this case, will check if the scope of existing access_token (for already logged in fb user), is a subset of that requested on the fb-login-button attribute. fb-login-button will display the authorize dialog for you automatically in this case. In any case the onLogin callback is triggered (when the login-button should be hidden() and the remaining page/forms be shown()).
4. Subscribe to the FB.events to get the authResponses and the corresponding access_token every time it is set, which happens 2 times :
   a. When the fetch is first displayed for already logged in user
   b. After the user authorizes the app first time or second time with the new scope.
   This allows you to keep the authResponse and access_token fresh to be used for all subsequent graph calls/etc..

**Implementation Steps **

1. fb-login-button must be created with onlogin callback :

   `<div class="fb-login-button" onLogin="onLogin();" scope="publish_actions" 
             data-size="large">Use This App</div>`

Please note that the text does not say Login, but 'Use this App', since the button is displayed for authorization in addition to just logging in.

1. Subscribe to the Events.

   `// authRepsonse Change is needed when the user hits the UseApp button
   // and permissions are re-fetched - then a new token needs to be refreshed
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', handleResponseChange);`

   // when the user logins and all permissions are all set, clicking on the 
   // use-app will not do anything and authResponse will always be null.
   // so this subscription is necessary
   FB.Event.subscribe('auth.statusChange', handleResponseChange);
2. Login Function to hide Login button and display form.

      `function onLogin () {
           hideLogin();
           showMain();
       }`
3. Handle Status Changes to save Token.

   ```
   // global variable that contains the access_token 
   // for use in graph calls/etc.
   var authResponse = null;

   function handleResponseChange(response) {
       if (response && response.authResponse) {
           authResponse = response.authResponse
           if (response.status == 'connected') {
              updateUserInfo(response);
              return;
          }
       }
       else { 
          authResponse = null;
       }
       hideMain();
       showLogin();
   }
   ```

Hope this helps and I believe that this is probably the most optimal way of handling client side authentication flow without doing any extra authorization/login dialog and let FB sdk do the trick.